# Prove there cannot be an injection $f:Ord$ \ $T \to U$ for any set $U$.

Tags: set-theory, ordinals

I need to use **MK** to prove that:
If $T$ is a set of ordinals then  there cannot be  an injection $f:Ord$  \ $T \to U$ for any set $U$.

I have just seen a proof use ZF:

> Else, $V= \{u\in U:\exists a\in Ord$  \ $T\; (u=f(a))\}$ is a set, so
>   $\{f^{-1}(v):v\in V\} \cup T=Ord$ is a set. (But then $Ord +1=Ord \cup
> > \{Ord\}$ is an ordinal that's larger than any ordinal.)

but now I am asking if it is possible to modify the argument above to get the desired result by MK.

I think the key point is to conclude that $V$ and the preimage are both sets. In the ZF version of the proof, they are sets because:

> Since $f$ is injective we have $∀v∈V∃!a(f(a)=v)$.
>
> By Replacement $∃W∀a(ψ(a)⟹a∈W)$, where $ψ(a)$ is:$ ∃v∈V(f(a)=v).$
>
> By Comprehension there exists $X={a∈W(ψ(a))}$... Of course
>   $X=f^{−1}V$

So could someone give a proof using  MK to conclude that $V$ and the preimage are sets,or otherwise, prove the statement? Thanks a lot!

Comment: It's unclear to me what your difficulty is...all the axioms of ZFC are theorems of MK (interpreting all the variables as set variables), so any proof in ZFC immediately gives a valid proof in MK.

Comment: In any case, if you want a direct proof from the axioms of MK, you should say exactly what those axioms are for you, since there are a few different equivalent versions.

Comment: @EricWofsey To be honest I choosed another method to deal with this part of my big exercise question at last... But thanks for pointing it out. I would do so next time.